# LED power injection

Tags: power, led-strip

I'm trying to implement an LED project which consists of the following **components**:

- Mean Well UHP-350-12 / 12 V DC / 350W Power supply
- GLEDOPTO GL-C008P / LED controller
- RGBCCT 5050 60LEDs/m, 4 x 5m in length, 6 pins: +12V, R, G, B, C, W, rated 90W/5m

My **question**:
How do I do a power injection for this project? Would that only be done with the +12V line or where would the ground line have to go?

This is a **schematic** of the project without power injection:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best power injection method for addressable LED RGB Strips?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/520164/whats-the-best-power-injection-method-for-addressable-led-rgb-strips)

Comment: "Simple" 2-wire power injection only really works for "smart" LED strips. If you want the same benefits for your "dumb" LED strips then you need to run entirely separate 6-wire cables to separate sections of the strip. Running the +12V alone and 'injecting' it will help, but won't have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered

here: [Powering 30m of RGB LED strips?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/405863/powering-30m-of-rgb-led-strips)

and here:
[What's the best power injection method for addressable LED RGB Strips?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/520164/whats-the-best-power-injection-method-for-addressable-led-rgb-strips)

In summary: connect the ground and the 12V line from every strip directly to your powersupply

Comment: I'm sorry, it doesn't apply to my case, there is no GND line on the LED strip.

Comment: Common anode RGBetc, you need to wire up every single strip with +12 V and the individual colours (-).

Comment: You mean like this? https://imgur.com/a/GzBYDGN Orange lines meaning: each of the wires connected to the respective color of the other side, so orange line = 6 wires connected color to color. And BTW, the LED controller is rated 5A.

Comment: @Michael Yes, I think. Like an other commenter said more clearly under your answer "all you have to do is run the +12 and 5 grounds from the controller to each point you want to inject" . – 
user1850479

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found a solution, an RGB LED CW amplifier, which basically is a repeater. This should fit my scenario and power all LEDs evenly.

[image: schematics for 4 x 5 m RGB CCT strips with an LED CCT Repeater]

Comment: You only need one of those "amplifier" devices if you are using so much power that you need multiple power supplies. In this case you have a single power supply, so all you have to do is run the +12 and 5 grounds from the controller to each point you want to inject.